# PushPin and error UIElement.Arrange(finalRect) cannot be called with Infinite or NaN values in finalRect

Tags: windows-phone-7, pushpin

I have problem with my windows phone app. I have google for solution but I find out that better is to rewrite that page one more time so I do it however I still got this error and I don't know why. Here is my xaml code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="GeoWatcher.Watch"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="AplicationTitleTextBox" Text="GeoWatcher" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Your trip" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <my:Map Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,101,0,0" Name="MyMap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" CredentialsProvider=""/>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,23,0,0" Name="StopButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,47,0,0" Name="DistanceTextBlock" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Here is my C# code

```
public partial class Watch : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public IsolatedStorageFile myStore;
        GeoCoordinate destinationPointPosition;
        Pushpin destinationPointPushPin;
        Pushpin actualPositionPushPin;
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;


        public Watch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            this.DistanceTextBlock.Text = "";
            loadSelectedPoint();
            this.destinationPointPushPin = new Pushpin();
            this.destinationPointPushPin.Location = this.destinationPointPosition;
            this.MyMap.Children.Add(destinationPointPushPin);
            this.watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            this.watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
            this.watcher.Start();
            this.actualPositionPushPin = new Pushpin();
            this.actualPositionPushPin.Location = this.watcher.Position.Location;
            this.MyMap.Children.Add(this.actualPositionPushPin);
            this.MyMap.SetView(this.actualPositionPushPin.Location, 12);
        }

        void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            this.actualPositionPushPin.Location = e.Position.Location;  
        }
        private void loadSelectedPoint()
        {
            try
            {

                using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("folder\\selected.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore))
                {
                    // Read the data.
                    using (var isoFileReader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
                    {
                        String temp = isoFileReader.ReadLine();
                        string[] tab = temp.Split('@');
                        GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(tab[1]), double.Parse(tab[2]));
                        this.destinationPointPosition = geo;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception b)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(b.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

I checked and it load data correctly from file. The problem is I guess with pushpin but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: At what line of code is the error raised?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set a PushPin.Location to GeoCoordinate value of Unknown. Check the IsUnknown property of GeoCoordinate, and if it is true - don't show your pushpin.